# How to pass $scope variable from controller to directive using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made a simple directive that print an object:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.users=[
{name:'davidi',age:'23'},
{name:'karen',age:'43'},
{name:'lior',age:'22'}
];

});


app.directive("appCustomer", function() {

var htmlcode="<p ng-repeat='user in customerInfo'>{{user.name}}</p>\
";


return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
    customerInfo: '=info'
  },   
template : htmlcode
};
});
```

my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<app-customer info="users"></app-customer>

</div>


</body>
</html>


<script src="angularapp.js"></script>
```

i want simply access the $scope.users in my directive, to print the users object without the ng-repeat,
so i made it like that:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.users=[
{name:'davidi',age:'23'},
{name:'karen',age:'43'},
{name:'lior',age:'22'}
];

});


app.directive("appCustomer", function() {

var htmlcode="";
var userslength=3;


for(var i=0;i<userslength;i++)
{
    htmlcode=htmlcode+"<p>{{users["+i+"]['name']}}</p>";
}

return {
restrict: 'E', 
template : htmlcode
};
});
```

thats works fine, but when i replace the `userlength` to `$scope.users.length` , the app fail.
so my question is how can i access a $scope from the controller in the directive?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2v7he08/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to specify the `link` function

```js
app.directive("appCustomer", function() {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    var htmlcode = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < scope.users.length; i++) {
      element.text(Put your text here);
      // OR
      element.html(Put your HTML here);

    }
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    users: '=',
    link: link
  };
});
```

In the scope you will receive `users array`

2. The second is you can you element argument to put your data to template. Or create html template separately